# How to stop python from running certain 'if' code when the variable value doesn't match

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to create a decision menu in python 2.7.

Can't get the options to be individual and not in order.

anything other than `if` gives syntax error

> pc = pound conversion
>
> kc = kilogram conversion

```py
cont = 1
while cont == 1:

    if input("Would you like to convert to pounds or kilograms?") == 'pounds':
        pc = 1

    if pc == 1:
        kilograms = float(input("Enter the amount of kilograms:  "))
        pounds = kilograms / 2.205

        print('The amount of pounds you entered is ', kilograms,
                  ' This is ', pounds, ' pounds ')
        pc = 0
        if input('Do you want to go again? (y/n) ') == 'n':
            cont = 0

    if input("Would you like to convert to pounds or kilograms?") == "kilograms":
        kc = 1

    if kc == 1:
        pounds = float(input("Enter the amount of pounds:  "))
        kilograms = pounds * 2.2
        grams = kilograms * 1000

        print('The amount of pounds you entered is ', pounds,
                  ' This is ', kilograms, ' kilograms ', 'and', grams,
                  'grams' )
        kc = 0

    if input('Do you want to go again? (y/n) ') == 'n':
        cont = 0
```

typing in `kilograms` when first prompted gives "pc is not defined"

And the program only properly' runs if you type in `pounds` first, `kilograms` second

Comment: Right: if you type in anything except `pounds`, then `pc` is undefined when you reach the following statement.  What else are you expecting to happen?  It looks like you need to work through a tutorial on input checking.  Then, be more careful with your program logic.

Comment: Most of all, code only a few lines at a time.  You've written about 30 lines of code here without testing to see whether the first 5 do what you expect.

Comment: Yeah true. school assignment is due today haha

Comment: i'll go back though the basics and ask for help from someone else.

Comment: thanks for responding, at least :)

Comment: Hint: Store the result of `input` in a variable. Then, use that variable instead of `pc` with an `if`-`elif` block. For example, `s = input(...)`, then `if s == "pounds": ... elif s == "kilograms": ...` You may also want to handle input that is not `"pounds"` or `"kilograms"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True: #generic while statement, only way to exit is break
    choice = input("Would you like to convert to pounds or kilograms: ") #store our choice in a variable for later
    if choice == 'pounds':
        kilograms = float(input("Enter the amount of kilograms:  "))
        pounds = kilograms / 2.205
        print('The amount of killograms you entered is ', kilograms,
                  ' This is ', pounds, ' pounds ')

    elif choice == "kilograms": #use an elif and define a different specific statement
        pounds = float(input("Enter the amount of pounds:  "))
        kilograms = pounds * 2.2
        grams = kilograms * 1000

        print('The amount of pounds you entered is ', pounds,
                  ' This is ', kilograms, ' kilograms ', 'and', grams,
                  'grams' )

    elif choice == "quit":
        print("Goodbye!")
        break #use break to break out of a loop

    else: #use an else to define a generic statement
        print "%s is not a valid choice"%choice
        continue #use continue to return to the beginning of the loop without doing anything after

    do_continue = input('Do you want to go again? (y/n) ')
    if do_continue == 'y':
        pass #do nothing and continue

    elif do_continue == 'n':
        print("Goodbye!")
        break

    else:
        print("What language is that? We will go again anyways!")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'bug' in your code.

The variable `pc` is only defined if the first prompt  `== 'pounds'`. Therefor, you are getting the error message `pc is not defined` on line 7, because it is only defined if you type in 'pounds'.

Comment: Yeah I realized how stupid my question was just after posting it. Thanks for responding though :)